# How to create a CDialog transparent with Tree View Control in mfc cpp

Tags: c++, mfc, cdialog

I want to make my dialog transparent along with the tree control and the list box attached to it as transparent. I have gone through many samples and I am able to do it.

Dialog and tree control Transparent by:

```
BOOL CMyDlg::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC *pDC)
{
  pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
  return FALSE  ;
}
BOOL CMyTreeCtrl::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC *pDC)
{
  pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
  return TRUE  ;
}
```

Remaining controls of the dialog transparent by:

```
HBRUSH CMyDlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
   HBRUSH hbr = CDialog::OnCtlColor( pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);

   if( pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() == 1028 || pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() == 1036)
    {
        hbr = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(HOLLOW_BRUSH);
    }
    return hbr;
}
```

The problem that I am facing here is, my dialog is attached to a docking pane, the moment I drag it with mouse on my screen from its fixed position, it looses this transparency.

Also when I drag right to increase the size horizontally, it does not update the Dialog correctly. If I use `OnPaint()` it does update and dock with the same color settings but cannot apply transparency.

I have also tried creating a sample mfc project in VS2010 and used:

```
LONG ExtendedStyle = GetWindowLong(GetSafeHwnd(),GWL_EXSTYLE );
SetWindowLong(GetSafeHwnd(),GWL_EXSTYLE,ExtendedStyle | WS_EX_LAYERED );
::SetLayeredWindowAttributes(GetSafeHwnd(),RGB(255,255,0),255,LWA_COLORKEY );
```

Kindly guide me if I misunderstood something here. I guess I have used all the ways combined. But had no other option to get this done in one shot.

Comment: Goog! being a newbie, you have asked question with a lot of care.

Comment: Thank you..
I am still working on this problem and looking out for a solution to this.

Comment: add some more tags,to attract more problem solvers.